# Tomcat downloads pptx as zip

Tags: tomcat, download, mime-types

When i try to donwload a pptx file, it is downloaded as zip file. There is only tomcat server. This is not about apache web server. I have configured tomcat web.xml and added mime types for pptx file. Have you got any ideas on why it is downloaded as zip?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tomcat won't automatically ZIP files. Something else is involved.

Comment: I have configured web apache vhost file and it worked. You can see my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i resolved my problem. There is nothing wrong with tomcat server.xml. I have configured web server's apache configuration. In mime.conf file pptx, xlsx, ... already exists but when i added 
`AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation pptx`
 to httpd.conf, it worked.

Thanks